# Simple deletion of files using text file list won't work

Tags: macos, bash

I have to delete files specified by remove.txt
which looks like this:

```
    img_8138.dng.jpg
    img_8140.dng.jpg
    img_8141.dng.jpg
    img_8143.dng.jpg
```

I've tried several suggestions from the web:

`while read file; do rm "$file"; done < remove.txt`

`xargs -rd '\n' --arg-file=remove.txt rm -i --`

`rm $(cat /Volumes/space1/remove.txt)`

`xargs rm <remove.txt` etc

The files are in the current directory some of which
are to be deleted (remove.txt). Deletion works if I use rm
on the current directory. But using the list I get the
error below every time.

`rm: cannot remove ‘img_8147.dng.jpg’: No such file or directory`

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Do the lines in the file contain leading or trailing space characters?

Comment: @patrix There is no leading or trailing space characters.

Comment: Can you run your first command (`while` loop) with `do echo rm "$file"; done` and then just copy/paste one of the printed commands into the shell?

Answer (score 1):

That error is expected. There is no full path leading to the directory containing the files within `remove.txt`. Thus, when you run `rm $(cat /Volumes/space1/remove.txt)` outside of the directory these files reside in, you get that error.

Simply run:

```
cd /Volumes/space1; rm `cat remove.txt`
```

Or modify the `remove.txt` file to include the full path.

Comment: I neglected to mention in my post I had also tried with absolute paths. I checked patrix's suggestion about extra spaces, no luck. Then I tried your version and others I had used yesterday. All trys resulted in that darn error.

Comment: "I neglected to mention in my post I had also tried with absolute paths." What method did you use when you attempted this? I suggest modifying the original question to include this information for clarification's sake. Cheers.